# How to access methods from array element?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, class, methods

I've recently taken upon myself to add setter and getter methods to my class.
Since doing this, many parts of my code got broken and I'm unable to access getter methods.

Take the example below:

```
private loadInputs() : Input[] {
        var inputs = <Input[]>this.get('inputs');
    inputs.sort((a,b) => a.QuoteRef().localeCompare(b.QuoteRef()))
        return( inputs || [] );
    }
```

My input class has 2 variables,
_Project: string
_line: string
Which I access using a method QuoteRef()

```
public QuoteRef(): string {
    return this._Project.concat('-' + this._Line.toString().padStart(3,'0'));
  }
```

Whenever I try to access a method or a getter from my class on an item that is casted as an Input, I can see the variables (though not access them as they are private), but the prototype section doesn't contain any of the methods.

This triggers the following error in the website console:
TypeError: a.QuoteRef is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I got it to work by updating the code as follows:

```
inputs.sort((a,b) => {
      let first = new Input(a);
      let second = new Input(b);
      return first.QuoteRef().localeCompare(second.QuoteRef());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your complete class I can only guess, but I think that a and b in your sort are not of the type you expect. I can't see what this.get('inputs') does, but I suspect it is not returning an array with Input class objects. Hence the function cannot be found (is not a function). You could try:

```
inputs.sort((a,b) => {
  console.log(typeof a);
  console.log(typeof b);
  a.QuoteRef().localeCompare(b.QuoteRef());
})
```

and check what the type is. Then check what your this.get actually returns.

Edit: forgot to mention that your IDE probably does not warn you because you cast the output of this.get to <Input[]>.

Comment: I removed the cast to <Input[]> and that works just as well.
I tried to cast to see if this would give me access to the class methods, but alas...

The console.log give me type object which is normal I think.
A new Input() would also give me a typeof object.
Your proposal did give me an idea though and I reformatted the code and got it to work.